# Merge specific XML elements if element values are equal

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to sum the values of  "TotalAmount" and "Tax" with //Category/ID and //Category/Percent as unique value. The XSLT has to delete the duplicate(s) and sum the values of "TotalAmount and "Tax". So for this example, ID "S" AND Percent "21" is a duplicate and should be deleted. The required values should be added to the other record of  "S" and "21".

At this moment, I'm able to succeed for a part of the written requirements

Example 1: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93F8dUD/2
First merge is working fine. "S" and "21" are duplicates and the XSLT merge part is working for the first 2 records. However, it also merges the TotalAmount and Tax of the last 2 records, which shouldn't happen.

Example 2: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MXNWNA
XSLT is working for the first 2 records. No merge, ID "S" is a duplicate, but Percent isn't. For the last 2 records, the same issue as described in example 1.

Seems like a minor change would fix this issue, unfortunately, I'm not able to find it by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a single key that concatenates the two values and then simply an empty template for the duplicates and a sum for the relevant elements suffices:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="group" match="Total" use="concat(Category/ID, '|', number(Category/Percent))"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Total[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(Category/ID, '|', number(Category/Percent)))[1]))]"/>

    <xsl:template match="TotalAmount">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('group', concat(../Category/ID, '|', number(../Category/Percent)) )/TotalAmount)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Tax">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('group', concat(../Category/ID, '|', number(../Category/Percent)) )/Tax)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```